# define x-axe for time series data

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot time series data. I have generated my data with this code:

```
PlotDataKanada <- ts(SortDataKanada[SortDataKanada$`Influenza Season and Epidemiological Week`>=201101 & SortDataKanada$`Influenza Season and Epidemiological Week`<201401,]$TotalPatienten, frequency = 52, start = 2011, end = 2014)
```

and then plot it:

```
plot(PlotDataKanada,type="l",ylab="Number of Patients")
```

My data in `PlotDataKanada`:

```
Time Series:
Start = c(2011, 1) 
End = c(2014, 1) 
Frequency = 52 
  [1] 1323 1147 1145 1008  986 1034  958  816  789  692  499  427  406
 [14]  374  306  183  162  109   71   41   32    8    2    3    2    1
 [27]    2    3    2    2    2    2   NA    1    4    3    2    2    3
 [40]    6    6    2   10   14    8   13   26   15   30   72   64  102
 [53]  121  130  148  189  234  273  328  528  811  990 1128 1049  737
 [66]  605  626  590  369  345  231  179  113   58   33   27   16   11
 [79]    3    7    3   10    1    2    2    4    6    2    8    4   10
 [92]   24   14   31   83  126  185  302  389  843 1611 2528 3217 3729
[105] 2832 1805 1203  940  747  576  518  525  486  449  388  398  340
[118]  393  347  309  260  182   95   61   31   16    1    7   28    7
[131]    6   14   14   12   38   39   57  122  100  165  229  443  787
[144] 1313 1323 1147 1145 1008  986 1034  958  816  789  692  499  427
[157]  406
```

[image]

on x-axis I see float values 2011.0,2011.5,...

But I would like to have only integer values: 2011,2012,...

How should I change my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick solution would be this:

```
plot(PlotDataKanada,type="l",ylab="Number of Patients", xaxt= "n")
axis(1, seq(2011,2014))
```